# Generate and return result from the XML Document

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to generate XML to maintain the record of 10 users. I need to write a program, which takes
any input from the user from any interface and returns the user details by taking
the user information from XML document. Can someone help me?

I tried to link the XSLT file in visual studio using  in the XML file and implement the Javascript in the XSLT file. But the html contents in the XSLT file is not rendered in the browser.

Comment: Most browsers support linking to XSLT via e.g. `<?xml-stylesheet href="sheet.xslt" type="text/xsl"?>` only if you load the XML over HTTP(S). If you load directly from the file system the stylesheet is usually ignored.

Comment: Try to write your JavaScript in a external .js file and use a link to that file in your xslt. And use Visual Studio to transform the xml file using the xslt and send the html result to the client